# Virtual COM Port Using usbser.sys Keeps Dropping

Tags: windows-7, usb, serial-port, c#, com

I have a C# wpf application that is communicating with a device via a virtual com port over USB. This device is using the usbser.sys driver.

Everything works normally as expected and communication is fine between the device and my application.

I am by no means a hardware guru so am I lost when it comes to these drivers and such.

The problem is, my COM port for the device will be lost every so often...as if the device has come unplugged(which it has not).

The COM port never becomes available and often will completely disappear from the device manager...however sometimes it will stay in the device manager but the com port still does not exist as far as my app is concerned.

Often, I will have to reboot to get things working again.

I am wondering if there is an alternative driver I could try, or if there is something I am overlooking. Configuration in windows? etc??

Hopefully someone with more hardware experience can help.

Btw, I am running on Windows 7 Home edition.